# Can't copy a std::vector<std::function<void ()>> using uniform initialization. Is this correct?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

The following code does not compile in GCC 4.7.2 or Clang 3.2:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::function<void()>> a;
   std::vector<std::function<void()>> b{a};
}
```

The issue is that the compiler will try to create b using an initializer_list, when clearly it should just be calling the copy constructor. However this seems to be desired behavior because the standard says that initializer_list constructors should take precedence.

This code would work fine for other std::vector, but for a std::function the compiler can't know whether you want the initializer_list constructor or another one.

It doesn't seem like there is a way around it, and if that is the case then you can never use uniform initialization in templated code. Which would be a giant shame.

Visual Studio (2012 November CTP) on the other hand doesn't complain about this. But the initializer_list support is not very good in there at the moment, so it might be a bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [LWG 2132](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3473.html#2132) which is not yet a Defect Report but there's clear consensus (and implementation experience) to fix it.  The standard says that `std::function`'s constructor will accept any type, so because an initializer-list constructor is always preferred to other constructors if it's viable,  your code tries to construct a vector from an `std::initializer_list<std::function<void()>>` with a single element initialized from the object `a`. That then causes an error because although you can construct a `std::function<void()>` from `a` the resulting object isn't callable.

In other words the issue is that `std::function` has an unconstrained template constructor allowing conversion from any type.  That causes a problem in your case because initializer-list constructors are preferred to other constructors if viable, and the unconstrained `function` constructor means it's always possible to create an `initializer_list<function<void()>>` from any type so an initializer-list constructor is always viable.

The proposed resolution to 2132 prevents constructing a `std::function` from a non-callable type, so the initializer-list constructor isn't viable and the `vector` copy constructor is called instead.  [I implemented that resolution for GCC 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2012-04/msg00083.html), and it's already implemented in Clang's libc++ library too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The LWG 2132 link actually talks about a problem which is similar but different, that just so happens to also fix this issue. Meaning the problem will only be fixed for std::function, not for other types with templated constructors.

I think my new rule for uniform initialization is "use it wherever you can, except if the object has an initializer_list constructor. Then only use it if you want that constructor." Which also means that you can't use it in templated code.

Comment: I prefer the rule "don't write unconstrained constructor templates that allow implicit conversion from any type." If you don't create types like that then you won't cause problems for people who try to use your type with classes that have initializer-list constructors. The standard library didn't follow that rule, but that's being fixed for `std::function`.

Answer (score 5):

I can't see any reason why this shouldn't compile and both gcc (version 4.8.0 20121111) and clang (version 3.3 (trunk 171007)) compile the code. That said, "uniform initialization" is far from uniform: There are definitely cases where you can't use braces when invoking a constructor.

Comment: g++ 4.7.2 (`4.7.2-5ubuntu1`) doesn't compile the code. Very strange compiler error message: http://pastebin.com/b1mcbYRq

Comment: @leemes since the question opens with "The following code does not compile in GCC 4.7.2 or Clang 3.2:", I'm assuming the OP knows this (and is probably the reason for the question in the first place).

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah, but he didn't provide the compiler message. This is why I posted this comment in the first place.