# Overload resolution with std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, overloading

Consider this example of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<void()> func1_t;
typedef std::function<void(int)> func2_t;

struct X
{
   X (func1_t f)
   { }

   X (func2_t f)
   { }
};

int main ( )
{
   X x([](){ std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; });
}
```

I was sure that it shouldn't compile, because the compiler shouldn't be able to choose one of the two constructors. g++-4.7.3 shows this expected behavior: it says that call of overloaded constructor is ambiguous. However, g++-4.8.2 successfully compiles it.

Is this code correct in C++11 or it is a bug/feature of this version of g++?

Comment: The standard says that for the `template<class R, class... Args> template<class F> function<R(Args...)>::function(F f)` overload the type `F` must be callable with arguments of the types in `Args`. I assume this means the standard requires that constructor to be SFINAE'd away if it can't be, meaning your call is unambiguous.

Comment: @Simple: yes, that makes sense, but I didn't think that conversion to argument sfinae-failure could help overload resolution.

Comment: @Simple [res.on.required] "Violation of the preconditions specified in a function’s *Requires:* paragraph results in undefined behavior
unless the function’s *Throws:* paragraph specifies throwing an exception when the precondition is violated." SFINAE-failure is mentioned explicitly in the *Remarks:* section, e.g. [syserr.errcode.constructors]/7

Comment: @lisyarus [see previous comment] .. which technically makes it UB (not ill-formed); libstdc++ accepts it and does The Right Thing.

Comment: @dyp I thought my interpretation might be incorrect. :P Yours looks like an answer.

Comment: @dyp: what is UB? Constructing a std::function from an unappropriate type or constructing the type X in my example?

Comment: Constructing `func2_t` from type not Callable wrt to the "signature" `void(int)` is UB. I mean, AFAIK, even trying to do overload resolution here is UB, as it might or might not succeed.

Comment: @dyp: I still don't get how sfinae can do overload resolution here :(

Comment: @lisyarus The construction of `func2_t` from `[](){}` is not viable (in this implementation), since rejected via SFINAE. I'll make an example.

Comment: I'm confused. Why shouldn't `X(func1_t f)` be obviously a match, and `X(func2_t f)` be obviously _not_ a match?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731947/overloading-on-stdfunction is some explanation on why this shouldn't compile

Comment: try adding a dummy `int` inside the lambda parameter list and [it will select the other constructor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/209525a4cd284d0c)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++11...

Let's take a look at the specification of the constructor template of `std::function` (which takes any Callable): [func.wrap.func.con]/7-10

> ```
> template<class F> function(F f);
> template <class F, class A> function(allocator_arg_t, const A& a, F f);
> ```
>
> 7 *Requires:* `F` shall be `CopyConstructible`. `f` shall be `Callable` (20.10.11.2) for argument types `ArgTypes` and return type
>   `R`. The copy constructor and destructor of `A` shall not throw
>   exceptions.
>
> 8 *Postconditions:* `!*this` if any of the following hold:
>
> - `f` is a `NULL` function pointer.
> - `f` is a `NULL` pointer to member.
> - `F` is an instance of the function class template, and `!f`
>
> 9 Otherwise, `*this` targets a copy of `f` initialized with `std::move(f)`. [left out a note here]
>
> 10 *Throws:* shall not throw exceptions when `f` is a function pointer or a `reference_wrapper<T>` for some `T`. Otherwise, may throw
>   `bad_alloc` or any exception thrown by `F`’s copy or move constructor.

Now, constructing, or attempting to construct (for overload resolution) a `std::function<void(int)>` from a `[](){}` (i.e. with signature `void(void)`) violates the requirements of `std::function<void(int)>`'s constructor.

[res.on.required]/1

> Violation of the preconditions specified in a function’s *Requires:* paragraph results in undefined behavior unless the function’s *Throws:* paragraph specifies throwing an exception when the precondition is violated.

So, AFAIK, even the result of the overload resolution is undefined. Therefore, both versions of g++/libstdc++ are complying in this aspect.

---

In C++14, this has been changed, see [LWG 2132](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2132). Now, the converting constructor template of `std::function` is required to SFINAE-reject incompatible Callables (more about SFINAE in the next chapter):

> ```
> template<class F> function(F f);
> template <class F, class A> function(allocator_arg_t, const A& a, F f);
> ```
>
> 7 *Requires:* `F` shall be `CopyConstructible`.
>
> 8 *Remarks:* These constructors shall not participate in overload
>   resolution unless `f` is Callable (20.9.11.2) for argument types
>   `ArgTypes...` and return type `R`.
>
> [...]

The "shall not participate in overload resolution" corresponds to rejection via SFINAE. The net effect is that if you have an overload set of functions `foo`,

```
void foo(std::function<void(double)>);
void foo(std::function<void(char const*)>);
```

and a call-expression such as

```
foo([](std::string){}) // (C)
```

then the second overload of `foo` is chosen unambiguously: Since `std::function<F>` defines `F` as its interface to the outside, the `F` defines which argument types are passed into `std::function`. Then, the wrapped function object has to be called with those arguments (argument types). If a `double` is passed into `std::function`, it cannot be passed on to a function taking a `std::string`, because there's no conversion `double` -> `std::string`.
For the first overload of `foo`, the argument `[](std::string){}` is therefore not considered Callable for `std::function<void(double)>`. The constructor template is deactivated, hence there's no viable conversion from `[](std::string){}` to `std::function<void(double)>`. This first overload is removed from the overload set for resolving the call (C), leaving only the second overload.

Note that there's been a slight change to the wording above, due to [LWG 2420](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2420): There's an exception that if the return type `R` of a `std::function<R(ArgTypes...)>` is `void`, then any return type is accepted (and discarded) for the Callable in the constructor template mentioned above. For example, both `[]() -> void {}` and `[]() -> bool {}` are Callable for `std::function<void()>`. The following situation therefore produces an ambiguity:

```
void foo(std::function<void()>);
void foo(std::function<bool()>);

foo([]() -> bool {}); // ambiguous
```

The overload resolution rules don't try to rank among different user-defined conversions, and hence both overloads of `foo` are viable (first of all) and neither is better.

---

#### How can SFINAE help here?

Note when a SFINAE-check fails, the program isn't ill-formed, but the function isn't viable for overload resolution. For example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
auto foo(T) -> typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value >::type
{  std::cout << "foo 1\n";  }

template<class T>
auto foo(T) -> typename std::enable_if< not std::is_integral<T>::value >::type
{  std::cout << "foo 2\n";  }

int main()
{
    foo(42);
    foo(42.);
}
```

Similarly, a conversion can be made non-viable by using SFINAE on the converting constructor:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    template<class T, class =
             typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value >::type >
    foo(T)
    {  std::cout << "foo(T)\n";  }
};

struct bar
{
    template<class T, class =
             typename std::enable_if< not std::is_integral<T>::value >::type >
    bar(T)
    {  std::cout << "bar(T)\n";  }
};

struct kitty
{
    kitty(foo) {}
    kitty(bar) {}
};

int main()
{
    kitty cat(42);
    kitty tac(42.);
}
```

Comment: I thought that sfinae only deals with the function's signature being valid/invalid, but here is a conversion from argument. Is it also involved in sfinae?

Comment: I don't understand why [res.on.required] even applies. That should only come into play at runtime. There is no UB at compile-time. I think this is a straightforward SFINAE problem: one constructor matches, the other doesn't.

Comment: @TemplateRex Except that SFINAE isn't mandated here. [defns.undefined] states "Permissible undefined behavior
ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or
program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment [...]"

Comment: @lisyarus I've added an example for SFINAE applying in conversions. Essentially, overload resolution has to check if `42` can be converted to a `foo` for the first ctor of `kitty` and if it can be converted to a `bar` for the second ctor. There's no conversion from `int` to `bar`, since there's no ctor that can do that. The instantiation of `bar::bar(T)` fails for `T == int`, no specialization is therefore added to the overload set.

Comment: hm, OK. But going at it from first principles: the Holy Trinity of Name Lookup - Argument Deduction - Overload Resolution *always* has to be played out, why would [res.on.required] trump that? Suppose you would copy `std::function` and rename it to `my_function`. Why would a compiler treat that any different than `std::function`?

Comment: @dyp: thanks a lot, now I get it. But it seems that it's not UB, just as TemplateRex said, and newer versions of libstdc++ have std::function's ctors sfinae-guarded, while older ones don't.

Comment: @lisyarus When you look at it from the runtime perspective: `std::function<void(int)> f = [](){};` surely is UB (at run-time), since it violates the *Requires*. But it can only be UB *at run-time* if it compiles.

Comment: @dyp: so, in my case the proper constructor of std::function is called and there is no UB?

Comment: @TemplateRex I'm not sure I understand what you're saying with *"why would [res.on.required] trump that"*. What I mean is: Once there's UB in your program, the implementation is free to reject the program (with an error), emit nasal daemons at run-time and so on; but there's also the possibility to change the behaviour of overload resolution, from *ambiguous* to *selecting a certain function*.

Comment: @dyp [take this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4732106/819272): " The compiler can't know until after a constructor template is selected and instantiated that it's going to run into errors, and it has to be able to select an overload of your function before it can do that." That's basically my argument.

Comment: Just to point out, there certainly can be undefined behaviour at compile time; see ODR violations.

Comment: @lisyarus I'd say that *for good implementations*, your program will either fail to compile or select the intended function. But I'd say a [DS9K implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:CompuHacker/CHDS9000) might select the *other* function.

Comment: @TemplateRex There's a bit of discussion about SFINAE in the comments to that answer. In accordance to those, I'd say that *in some situations*, you can see while instantiating that selecting the ctor would not result in something useful and reject it via SFINAE. That is of course only allowed if the Standard gives you leeway to do so, and IMO it does by saying that selecting the ctor *results in* UB.

Comment: @TemplateRex Actually, that quote sounds wrong to me. In order to check for errors, you'll only need to deduce the types and substitute them. Then, you need to check if there's a conversion from the argument expression to the parameter type. The compiler needs to check whether or not that conversion is possible *before* selecting an overload, since it determines which overloads are *viable*.

Comment: Please leave a comment if you downvote so I can improve my answer.

Comment: (For the record, it wasn't me who downvoted, at the contrary): I wanted just to point out this [DR](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2132) which gcc is already implementing.

Comment: The issue with these `std::function` constructors is really nasty. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087600/cant-copy-a-stdvectorstdfunctionvoid-using-uniform-initialization-i/14090711#14090711).

Answer (score -3):

**It is totally valid.** Since c++11 lambda expressions (and your `std::function` wrapper) create function objects. The great strength of function objects is that, even when they are generic, they remain first-class objects. Unlike ordinary function templates, they can be passed to and returned from functions.

You can create operator overload sets explicitly with inheritance and using declarations. The following usage from [Mathias Gaunard](https://plus.google.com/109462007708056630177/posts) demonstrates “overloaded lambda expressions".

```
template <class F1, class F2>
struct overload_set : F1, F2
{
    overload_set(F1 x1, F2 x2) : F1(x1), F2(x2) {}
    using F1::operator();
    using F2::operator();
};

template <class F1, class F2>
overload_set<F1,F2> overload(F1 x1, F2 x2)
{
    return overload_set<F1,F2>(x1,x2);
}

auto f = overload(
    [](){return 1;}, 
    [](int x){return x+1;}
);

int x = f();
int y = f(2);
```

[source](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2012/09/unifying-generic-functions-and-function-objects/)

**EDIT:** Maybe it'll become more clear if in the provided example you replace

```
F1 -> std::function<void()> 
F2 -> std::function<void(int)>
```

and [see it compile in gcc4.7](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%2BAKFElkVQDMZJsMwCpyzsBPABwUVqQ44ALmH1GzFADd0IOAAokSgJQkkAMQCMAbg48%2BCAUNHiITdGGmyF4bKo0AmXWRy4YZpOikJcUdATgAfUwEbCRhDU0AGkcyAG8yAEgvHz8A4ND5LSQAD2jHXIdlcMj5POUY9QcyoqQ4gF8kmExwAHNI0XReXAJsdFx5ZV1E5rbHTu7e%2FsHdeucU338gkLCFtIVsvMqHQuV4pPxsGFwwT29F9JWy6Jyi2bIyWyQiAnBB%2FcSCGD6kAQBeM6pJbyMhKMFIADaAF1BuClHFBNgRMIIOhvqgUEgAESKFSAi5wAA6YCx2nqMVBcOh8ieOWKCOMKLRYRQmJxtmKayWxNJ9SGD0StBmSSFdwFh2OpwADLMgAAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fg%2B%2B-4.7%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B0x%22%7D%5D%7D)

The templated solution was only provide to demonstrate that concept scales to generic code and dissambiguation is possible.

**In your case, when using an older compiler like gcc 4.7**, you could help by explicit cast and [gcc will work things out, as you can see in this live example](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%2BAKFElkVQDMZJsMwCpyzsBPABwUVqQ44ALmH1GzFADd0IOAAoAlCSTiIARgD62ANwcefBAKGi1TdGGmyF4bMtUMIAJm16yOXDAjYkADTIA3mRIIb5I8mpaPrSKwSEBSAC%2BZHF%2B4Wou0bEhSAnJiW62SEQE4OFIsUGhSOgARgBW6vKC2CJijuaWMnJKJM0A2gC6SgkARAASCFBQ6AA0SADu6LhQcACEADpgozpJFRV6IXFhdfVOzSbtEhZWPbbKA8NFANaKY5PTc4vLq5vbu4l9oo9IkgAAA%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fg%2B%2B-4.7%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B0x%22%7D%5D%7D)

Just in case you're wondering, it wouldn't work if you cast the other way around (try to convert the lambda taking int to the std::function taking no arguments and so on)

Comment: There is no overloading a lambda object in my example

Comment: `X x([](){ std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; });`

Comment: Where do you see overloading a lambda's operator() ?

Comment: How do you think the compiler chooses the constructor for `func1_t f`?  If you called it with `X x([](int k){ std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; });` what version would be chosen?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking; it has nothing to deal with overloading the lambda's operator() itself.

Comment: It's not the lambdas operator that is overloaded. It's the constructor that overloads on first class object arguments. Then one of them (`std::function<void()`) matches the closure type `[]()`. I'm just saying that and providing a similar example of how to extend the concept.

Comment: *"Then one of them (`std::function<void()>`) matches the closure type `[]()`"* Match in which sense? The closure type of `[]{}` is a unique, unnamed class unrelated to `std::function<void()>`. The latter has a converting constructor that accepts any argument expression that meets the `Callable` requirements for the return type `void` and no arguments.

Comment: Like all callable objects, closures can be captured in std::function. `<void()>` matches `[]()->void` and `<void(int)>` matches            `[](int)->void`. Being unnamed doesn't mean it has no type and that type conversion rules can't apply. If it wasn't for that lambdas and std::function wouldn't be interchangeable in calling STL algorithms or there wouldn't be any typesafety there. Ofcourse gcc4.8 has a better support for this feature, and this conversion applies in lots of powerfull techniques like the one I showcased (creation of overload sets)