# Using SFINAE with generic lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, sfinae, generic-lambda

Can generic lambdas take advantage of the *"Substitution Failure Is Not An Error"* rule ? Example

```
auto gL = 
    [](auto&& func, auto&& param1, auto&&... params) 
        -> enable_if_t< is_integral<
            std::decay_t<decltype(param1)>
        >::value>
    {
        // ...
    };

auto gL =  
     [](auto&& func, auto&& param1, auto&&... params) 
        -> enable_if_t< !is_integral<
            std::decay_t<decltype(param1)>
        >::value>
    {
        // ...
    };
```

Are there any workarounds or plans to include this in the language ? Also since generic lambdas are templated function objects under the hood isn't it a bit odd that this can't be done ?

Comment: Your lambda seems to [work just fine](http://ideone.com/rFOkmA) as written?

Comment: @KerrekSB OK that's awesome, should I rephrase the question to focus on the SFINAE bit ?

Comment: I have no idea what problem you need to solve...

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem if you're simply returning the result of the function call, even if the function returns `void`. The problem arises when you need to store the return value temporarily, do something else, and then return it (or not return anything in case of `void` return type). In that case you can probably work around it by creating an RAII wrapper that does the *do something else* part in its destructor. Or tag dispatch to other lambdas/functions based on `result_of`.

Comment: @Praetorian I was just writing this exact thing. Modified the example. The question is about **using SFINAE with generic lambdas**. Can it be done, will it be done, why can't it, shouldn't it ? ...

Comment: @RyanHaining What does the return type have to do with benchmarking ?

Comment: `Timer t; return f(args...);`, and `Timer::~Timer` prints the result.

Comment: I misunderstood the comments, I read it as `func` returning some `timer` which is assigned to `k`

Comment: you want to SFINAE without overloading?

Comment: sfinae works only when there is a better overload to pick when the first one errors. Since you can't overload lambdas it is not clear what sfinae will achieve.

Comment: @Dani this is a perfect reason (also pointed out by Ryan). I was caught up on the _"it's all templated function object under the hood"_ rationale that I forgot about overloading lamdas. I don't understand why don't you post it as an answer

Comment: You're allowed to use expression SFINAE in the trailing return type, [here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a24f8405dd8f9612) a modified version of Kerrek's example that rejects `void` return type. What you cannot do is provide a complementary version that only works for `void` return type.

Comment: @Yakk I beg to disagree. Adding bolg gives emphasis (greek έμφασις = εν + φαινομαι = make something appear). Please re-read the question. This is not an implementation problem but a question about the language and a feature (SFINAE for generic lambdas)

Comment: Much better!  Comments deleted, vote reversed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lambdas are function objects under the hood.  Generic lambdas are function objects with template `operator()`s.

```
template<class...Fs>
struct funcs_t{};

template<class F0, class...Fs>
struct funcs_t<F0, Fs...>: F0, funcs_t<Fs...> {
  funcs_t(F0 f0, Fs... fs):
    F0(std::move(f0)),
    funcs_t<Fs...>(std::move(fs)...)
  {}
  using F0::operator();
  using funcs_t<Fs...>::operator();
};
template<class F>
struct funcs_t<F>:F {
  funcs_t(F f):F(std::move(f)){};
  using F::operator();
};
template<class...Fs>
funcs_t< std::decay_t<Fs>... > funcs(Fs&&...fs) {
  return {std::forward<Fs>(fs)...};
}
```

`auto f_all = funcs( f1, f2 )` generates an object that is an overload of both `f1` and `f2`.

```
auto g_integral = 
  [](auto&& func, auto&& param1, auto&&... params) 
    -> std::enable_if_t< std::is_integral<
        std::decay_t<decltype(param1)>
    >{}>
  {
    // ...
  };

auto g_not_integral =  
 [](auto&& func, auto&& param1, auto&&... params) 
    -> std::enable_if_t< !std::is_integral<
        std::decay_t<decltype(param1)>
    >{}>
{
    // ...
};

auto gL = funcs( g_not_integral, g_integral );
```

and calling `gL` will do SFINAE friendly overload resolution on the two lambdas.

The above does some spurious moves, which could be avoided, in the linear inheritance of `funcs_t`.  In an industrial quality library, I might make the inheritance binary rather than linear (to limit instantiation depth of templates, and the depth of the inheritance tree).

---

As an aside, there are 4 reasons I know of to SFINAE enable lambdas.

First, with new `std::function`, you can overload a function on multiple different callback signatures.

Second, the above trick.

Third, currying a function object where it evaluates when it has the right number and type of args.

Forth, automatic tuple unpacking and similar.  If I'm using continuation passing style, I can ask the passed in continuation if it will accept the tuple unpacked, or the future unbundled, etc.

Comment: Now I remember posting about [creating overload sets for lambda functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22147375/2567683) (equally poor received). Sorry for the confusion, I should have phrased my question better from the beggining, this is a nice topic and it's a pitty it'll be overlooked

Answer (score 2):

The use of SFINAE is to remove an overload or a specialization from the candidate set when resolving a given function or template. In your case, we have a lambda - that is a functor with a single `operator()`. There is no overload, so there is no reason to use SFINAE<sup>1</sup>. The fact that the lambda is generic, which makes its `operator()` a function template, doesn't change that fact.

However, you don't actually need to differentiate between different return types. If `func` returns `void` for the given arguments, you can still `return` it. You just can't assign it to a temporary. But you don't have to do that either:

```
auto time_func = [](auto&& func, auto&&... params) {
    RaiiTimer t;
    return std::forward<decltype(func)>(func)(
        std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...); 
};
```

Just write an `RaiiTimer` whose constructor starts a timer and whose destructor stops it and prints the result. This will work regardless of `func`'s return type.

If you need something more complicated than that, then this is one of those cases where you should [prefer a functor over a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27256160/2069064).

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, as Yakk points out, SFINAE could still be quite handy to check if your function is callable period, which isn't the problem you're trying to solve - so in this case, still not very helpful.

Comment: A SFINAE enabled lambda can be tested against (can I call it with some stuff or not?), so it is quite useful.  As an example, I can take a SFINAE enhanced lambda and pass it to a [`curry(F)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26655685/1774667) function, and have it invoke when I have passed enough parameters.  Or I could collect a bunch of lambdas, aggregate them into one object, and use SFINAE to determine which one I should dispatch a call to (an overload set of lambdas).  SFINAE lamdas have *early failure*, which is useful even outside of overload resolution.

Comment: ... How do you know what problem the OP is trying to solve?  Can you understand the question beyond the title?  How is that possible?

Comment: @Yakk I think he just wants to to time any `func` and have `gL` return the result (or not)?

Answer (score 2):

A generic lambda can only have one body, so SFINAE wouldn't be of much use here.

One solution would be to package the call into a class which can store the result and is specialized on a `void` return type, encapsulating the `void` special handling away from your lambda.  With a very little overhead, you can do this using the thread library facilities:

```
auto gL = 
    [](auto&& func, auto&&... params)
    {
        // start a timer
        using Ret = decltype(std::forward<decltype(func)>(func)(
            std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...));
        std::packaged_task<Ret()> task{[&]{
            return std::forward<decltype(func)>(func)(
                std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...); }};
        auto fut = task.get_future();
        task();
        // stop timer and print elapsed time
        return fut.get(); 
    };
```

If you want to avoid the overhead of `packaged_task` and `future`, it's easy to write your own version:

```
template<class T>
struct Result
{
    template<class F, class... A> Result(F&& f, A&&... args)
        : t{std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<A>(args)...)} {}
    T t;
    T&& get() { return std::move(t); }
};
template<>
struct Result<void>
{
    template<class F, class... A> Result(F&& f, A&&... args)
        { std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<A>(args)...); }
    void get() {}
};

auto gL = 
    [](auto&& func, auto&&... params)
    {
        // start a timer
        using Ret = decltype(std::forward<decltype(func)>(func)(
            std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...));
        Result<Ret> k{std::forward<decltype(func)>(func),
            std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...};
        // stop timer and print elapsed time
        return k.get(); 
    };
```